# How can I make PHP name this div?

Tags: php, css, html

So I want php to name the div whatever the value of B is. Example: if b = 1, I want the div id to be "imgDiv-1". The code generates 3 divs, and each div has to have a different name. However, this code makes every div id to be "imgDiv-3"
Code:

```
<?php
for ($b=3; $b > 4; $b++) {
    define('RANDOM_IMAGES_COUNT2',3);
    define('RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT2', '<div id="imgDiv-' .$b. '"style="width:170px; height:auto;float:left;text-align:center;top"><img src="%s" style="border-style:solid;border-width:2px;border-color:black;"/><a href="%s" alt="%s" title2="%s">%s</a></div>');
}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$images = array (
    array ( 'title2' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => 'pic2.jpg', 'href2' => 'http://mylink.com  /path/','text2' => 'Hello' ),
    array ( 'title2' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => 'pic7.jpg', 'href2' => 'http://mylink.com/path/','text2' => 'Hello2' ),
    array ( 'title2' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => 'pic9.jpg', 'href2' => 'http://mylink.com/path/','text2' => 'Hello2' ), 
    array ( 'title2' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => 'pic5.jpg', 'href2' => 'http://mylink.com/path/','text2' => 'Hello2' ),     
    array ( 'title2' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => 'pic3.jpg', 'href2' => 'http://mylink.com/path/','text2' => 'Hello3' )
);

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if ( count($images) < RANDOM_IMAGES_COUNT2 ) {
    trigger_error('Not enough images given', E_USER_WARNING);
    exit;
}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

for ($i = 0; $i < RANDOM_IMAGES_COUNT2; $i++) {
    shuffle($images);

    $tmp = array_shift($images);
    printf( RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT2, $tmp['src2'], $tmp['href2'], $tmp['title2'],     $tmp['title2'],$tmp['text2'] );    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has multiple issues.

Firstly, your loop never runs. You initalize `$b` to 3 and have it run while `$b > 4`, which is never the case. You probably wanted this: `for ($b=1; $b < 4; $b++)`

Secondly, you need to understand what [`define()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) does. It defines a **constant**, which cannot be changed. So setting it within a loop is a no-no.

Perhaps this is what you wanted?

```
define('RANDOM_IMAGES_COUNT', 3);
define('RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT', '
    <div id="imgDiv-%s" style="width:170px; height:auto; float:left; text-align:center;">
        <img src="%s" style="border-style:solid; border-width:2px; border-color:black;" />
        <a href="%s" alt="%s" title2="%s">%s</a>
    </div>
');

$images = array (
    array ( 'title2' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => 'pic2.jpg', 'href2' => 'http://mylink.com  /path/','text2' => 'Hello' ),
    array ( 'title2' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => 'pic7.jpg', 'href2' => 'http://mylink.com/path/','text2' => 'Hello2' ),
    array ( 'title2' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => 'pic9.jpg', 'href2' => 'http://mylink.com/path/','text2' => 'Hello2' ), 
    array ( 'title2' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => 'pic5.jpg', 'href2' => 'http://mylink.com/path/','text2' => 'Hello2' ),     
    array ( 'title2' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => 'pic3.jpg', 'href2' => 'http://mylink.com/path/','text2' => 'Hello3' )
);
if (count($images) < RANDOM_IMAGES_COUNT) {
    trigger_error('Not enough images given', E_USER_WARNING);
    exit;
}
shuffle($images);
for ($i=1; $i<=RANDOM_IMAGES_COUNT; $i++) {
    printf(
        RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT,
        $i,
        $images[$i]['src2'],
        $images[$i]['href2'],
        $images[$i]['title2'],
        $images[$i]['title2'],
        $images[$i]['text2']
    );
}
```

Comment: The images and the text2 is not displaying now for some reason :I. Instead, now the Test 2 is a hyperlink, which if clicked navigates to the image...

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `$b=3` to start with and the loop can only run while `$b` is less than 4 (so when `$b` is 3...which it is) then your loop is pointless. `$b` can never be equal to 1.

Perhaps you want to do this: `for ($b=1; $b < 4; $b++) {`.

This means that `$b` will be 1 at first, then run the code again as 2, then 3, and then will will be done.

Comment: Oops, that was meant to be a `<` :) Updated.

Comment: Awesome job, all 3 people that copied my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

so all in all, from all the comments you should probably change the for loop to match

```
for($b = 1; $b < 4; b++)
{
}
```

this will make

```
imgDiv-1, imgDiv-2, imgDiv-3
```

also if you have any question using DEFINE()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

is a good resource

Answer (score 0):

Change in for loop

Write

```
for ($b=1; $b < 4; $b++) {
        define('RANDOM_IMAGES_COUNT2',3);
        define('RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT2', '<div id="imgDiv-' .$b. '"style="width:170px; height:auto;float:left;text-align:center;top"><img src="%s" style="border-style:solid;border-width:2px;border-color:black;"/><a href="%s" alt="%s" title2="%s">%s</a></div>');
    }
```

Instead of

```
for ($b=3; $b > 4; $b++) {
    define('RANDOM_IMAGES_COUNT2',3);
    define('RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT2', '<div id="imgDiv-' .$b. '"style="width:170px; height:auto;float:left;text-align:center;top"><img src="%s" style="border-style:solid;border-width:2px;border-color:black;"/><a href="%s" alt="%s" title2="%s">%s</a></div>');
}
```